# Forma correcta y mas segura de hacer consultas php con jquery

Tags: jquery

Mayormente para "obtener" algun tipo de dato hago lo siguiente:

```
  $.ajax({
    url: "boxs.php", type: 'POST', data: 'modo=' + modo + adicional, dataType: 'HTML',
    success: function (resp) {
      $("body").prepend(resp);
    }
  });
```

usandolo asi me parece normal, y literalmente seguro; pero el problema esta en que tambien lo uso para interactuar con mi base de datos (crear,editar,eliminar,etc).
Mi pregunta es: existe otra forma "mas segura" de hacer esta accion usando jquery ?

Comment: ¿Por qué consideras que no es tan segura?

Comment: El problema, no está en como hacés las consultas desde jQuery, sino en como las armás desde PHP. Podrías poner un ejemplo?

Comment: @BetaM me parece que expongo la url boxs.php y que mando los datos directamente. no vi otras paginas hacer lo mismo.

Comment: @azeós yo valido de parte del servidor y del front todo pero me parece que estoy exponiendo mucho como funciona mi sistema con esas variables y la url php

Comment: En el cliente no puedes ocultar nada, por más falsos trucos que haya, es imposible ocultar en este caso que las peticiones van dirigidas a `boxs.php`. Eso signifca que debes asegurar: 1. que las consultas que se hagan en la base de datos sean consultas preparadas (no mandar a consulta directamente los datos que pasas en `data`); 2. filtrar esos datos a nivel de HTML si serán usados como parte de la respuesta; 3. montar un sistema de validación en el cliente, verificando en el servidor (login, tokens) para asegurarte que el usuario que se conecta desde el cliente tiene privilegios para ...

Comment: ... efectuar las operaciones que son permitidas desde esa página (consultar, borrar, eliminar datos). En resumen, la seguridad no está en que se vea o no se vea un archivo lo cual como ya dije es imposible, un hacker mediocre sabrá encontrar que el punto de entrada hacia el servidor es `boxs.php`, poco importa que eso se conozca, si tienes tu código blindado **a todos los niveles y aplicando en cada caso el tipo de seguridad que corresponda**. Aún así, nada en esta vida es 100% seguro, pero haciendo eso, tendrás un 99,9999999% de seguridad en tu código.

Comment: Perfecto, gracias por tu comentario, a seguir mejorando la seguridad de mi codigo